# finding partial derivative of two equal functions gives different results

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, partial-derivative, exponentiation

$e^{\ln[x+w]} = xw$

I hope we agree left side is equal to right side.

Finding partial derivative $w$ given right side is simply $x$

But when I used online partial derivative calculator and I tried to find partial derivative of $w$ given left function, it would outcome $1$.

https://www.symbolab.com/solver/partial-derivative-calculator

My question is, how is this possible? Should left side produce same result? I double checked that left side is equal to right side.

Comment: The problem is in the very first equation. It is generally false, what you rather have is that $e^{x+w}=\log(x+w).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't agree that the left side is equal to the right side, since$$e^{\log(x+w)}=x+w\ne xw.$$And, yes,$$\frac\partial{\partial w}e^{\log(x+w)}=\frac\partial{\partial w}(x+w)=1.$$

Comment: You must be way better mathematican than me, this is how I see it:
log(5+10) with base two = 3,90.. if we power 3.9 with get 15. Wouldn't this be right?

Comment: Don't you agree that we always have $e^{\log x}=x$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Would it be correct to say $exp(ln(x)) * exp(ln(w)) = x*w$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, now it's the correct result. need to work on my algebra:)